# hi , any idea how to make auto inferring a tuple?

Tags: typescript

any idea how to make auto inferring a tuple ? current inference is (string|boolean)[] , the issue here is i want only one case (A) to have the array of false and string , and the others to be a Boolean values only.
how to achieve this with auto inference  or any other method without having to type the whole object since it is kind of long.

```js
const inicialErrState: { [key: string]: boolean; a: [boolean, string] } = {
    a: [false, ''],
    b: false,
    c: false,
    d: false,
  };
```

Comment: auto infracting? Do you maybe mean auto inferring?

Comment: You can try ```type InitialErrorState = { [key: string]: [boolean, string] | boolean } & { a: [boolean, string] };```. This forces `a` to be a tuple of `[boolean, string]`, but all the other fields can be either a tuple or a boolean, so it's not a perfect solution.

Comment: @anut worked please put an answer. actually all other values are Boolean.. for some reason

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wQ8zAW) work for you?  If not, what am I missing about the question?

Comment: it is excluding all except the a value so dont make sense but it is working

Comment: @jcalz works as well ...... it dealers this part of the object as a tuple really good solution

Comment: I am not sure I understand you.  Do you want me to write an answer?  Or do you want to use the other answer?

Comment: @jcalz your answer solves my issue as well both your answer and anut answer are good your how ever is kind cleaner ... not to bash on anut!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use a helper function which infers tuple types:

```
const tuple = <T extends any[]>(...t: T) => t;

const initialErrState = {
    a: tuple(false, ''),
    b: false,
    c: false,
    d: false,
};
/* const initialErrState: {
    a: [boolean, string];
    b: boolean;
    c: boolean;
    d: boolean;
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=4&ts=4.7.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCuAHANgUxgXhgHgCo1QA8pUwATCGAQzAE8BtAXQD4AKAOk6gC4ZcBKTMzgBuAFBjQkWAEswMqDKrIAogCc1AZShUSmGAG8xME9V4IUqVgDNlEVABoYAcmf8Hx0wCNet5PY9TGGBfO0dPEzJQ-3CAX3EAegAqYPBoGDkFJVUNbV1UXiMgql56LxAQNBonaDU5AHNGcSCfGHLK1Bpm0xC2iqqwbsjedoHxWJgkhKA)

Comment: an awesome and great way to leverage generics....

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following type. This enforces that `a` is a tuple, but it allows all other values to be either a boolean or a tuple, so it's not a perfect solution. It may work well enough for your use case, though.

```
type InitialErrorState = {
  [key: string]: [boolean, string] | boolean
} & {
  a: [boolean, string]
};
```

Comment: the issue here is it simply over write only the a value other values are only Boolean rather than [Boolean, string] | Boolean